# Get json response in one big table

Tags: python, json, pandas

i am currently dabbeling in creating pipelines with python, which is really fun, but currently am really stuck: i am trying to get a json response in one big table, recursively.

I am specifically trying to make this generic: not name all parts, but be able to use the same script on other json files as well.

Do you guys have any suggestions? (am still very green).

As a json example:

```
{
"area": {
    "id": 2072,
},
"competition": {
    "id": 2021,
},
"season": {
    "id": 733,
},
"standings": [
    {
        "type": "TOTAL",
        "table": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "team": {
                    "id": 65,
                    "name": "Manchester City FC",
                },
                "playedGames": 37,
            },
            {
                "position": 2,
                "team": {
                    "id": 64,
                    "name": "Liverpool FC",
                },
                "playedGames": 36,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "HOME",
        "table": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "team": {
                    "id": 64,
                    "name": "Liverpool FC",
                },
                "playedGames": 18,
            },
            {
                "position": 2,
                "team": {
                    "id": 65,
                    "name": "Manchester City FC",
                },
                "playedGames": 18,
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

}

The output i would want in this case would be:

[image: table]

The code i'm currently using:

```
import pandas as pd

def flatten_json(json_data, prefix=''):
flattened_data = {}
for key, value in json_data.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        flattened_data.update(flatten_json(value, prefix + key + '.'))
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(value):
            flattened_data.update(flatten_json(item, prefix + key + '.' + str(i) + '.'))
    else:
        flattened_data[prefix + key] = value
return flattened_data



flattened_data = flatten_json(json_data)
df = pd.DataFrame([flattened_data])
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: '.'.join(x.split('.')[-2:]) if '.' in x else x)
df = df[df.columns.dropna()]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) your data then do a bit of *post-processing* :

```
df = (
    pd.json_normalize(
        json_data, ["standings", "table"],
        meta=[["standings", "type"]], record_prefix="standings.table.")
    .assign(**{f"{k}.id": json_data[k]["id"]
               for k in ("area", "competition", "season")})
)
```

Output :

| standings.table.position | standings.table.playedGames | standings.table.team.id | standings.table.team.name | standings.type | area.id | competition.id | season.id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 37 | 65 | Manchester City FC | TOTAL | 2072 | 2021 | 733 |
| 2 | 36 | 64 | Liverpool FC | TOTAL | 2072 | 2021 | 733 |
| 1 | 18 | 64 | Liverpool FC | HOME | 2072 | 2021 | 733 |
| 2 | 18 | 65 | Manchester City FC | HOME | 2072 | 2021 | 733 |